# ID3 visualization using WEKA API

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka

How to use WEKA API to generate graphical visualization of ID3? I mean programmatically, using Java and the WEKA API, not using the WEKA application itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weka API can be used with Java, check [this](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/)

In this website check Miscellaneous Code link on the left side of page.

Not only this you can use Weka with other languages too.

Comment: Thanks. I found exactly what I need in http://weka.wikispaces.com/Visualizing+a+Tree